# Are Firebug waterfall charts accurate?

Tags: php, performance, apache, firebug

When loading my site http://www.wealthdaily.com/, (the site is in php) firebug is saying that small (< 5 kb) images are taking over 5 SECONDS to load!  This is not blocking but it is killing overall page load time. Images are being loaded by apache with mod_rewrite.

When I load one of the images individually firebug says it only take ~ < 20 ms for each image, which sounds like it is more accurate. I realize lots of things are going on on the full page load that could influence this, but cause these to take 4 seconds apiece to load, seems a little far out.

The images are Loading fine, it's the speed that firefox claims they are loading at.  Smallish images are taking 5 seconds. Could a misconfigured apache be causing this slowness when there are lots of requests??

Is there a tool that can accurately time how long it takes for a page to load?
Is firebug to be trusted????

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd trust Firebug

Web Inspector in Chrome is showing images downloaded from images.angelpub.com are slow too.

Out of curiosity... Why are you loading these images using https?

Setting up connection appears to be part of the slowness - is the other end of images.angelpub.com a VPS, if so what size/power?

Answer (score 1):

> Is firebug to be trusted?

I would generally trust it however, you should read the usage terms (excerpt):

> **THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED** BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS **"AS IS"** AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, **THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED**. [highlights by me]

What you describe can have multiple causes. For example your server might be just slow by the number of requests, as well there might be an incompatibility with the browser.

Firebug displays the time Firefox takes to load the images. Reload the page and try again. If this does not help, metric the loading time with another benchmarking tool so you can compare what's causing long load times.

Comment: IIRC ab can do that incl. all linked files. However most of those tools do not support javascript generated requests.